# Modulator design in ADS

Tags: modulation, emitter-follower, cascode, ads

hello everyone editing my previous post, i have biased my circuit now i want to run it for s-parameters simulation but when i attach term port it is giving a negative S(1,1).. any help would be appreciated.. and when i remove the dc source attached to input for s parameters simulation it gives same biasing issues .. any leads..
i am working on a task of designing an IQ modulator, as i am working on a paper, i have designed the circuit attached below.
but it is giving a negative plot of S21, and few warnings, i am unable to figure out the problem... any leads would be appreciated.. [image: Schematic of my circuit]

Comment: You have your bias set at 3.3 volt and that won't work on a circuit that runs from 3.3 volts. The DC block capacitor is also pointless.

Comment: so any solutions for this ??

Comment: I'm just pointing out what appear to be anomalies. Given that you are designing it, you should take some action to try different bias values.